# How to show upper bound of 2 variable function

Tags: real-analysis

I just left an exam and was wondering about one task that seemed too hard for me. 
And at first i asked wolframalpha about the answer, of course i have given wrong one on the exam.

We have given $$\{\frac{2^{n+m}}{2^n + 2^{2m} + 2^{2n} }\}$$, where n and m are natural numbers. I farily easily showed that lower bound is 0. 
But it was so hard to came up with correct answer for upper bound. Wolframalpha says that this function takes maximum at n=45 and m=45 and is equal to $$\frac{35184372088832}{70368744177665}$$, what is super hard to come up with.
I think they could have accepted that this answer is about 1/2. BUT, we  had to tell if actual maximum/minimum is taken by this function and to proove it.

I'm first year student, so i don't know any fancy techniques to solve such problems and either i wouldn't understand hard solutions.

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this task! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not actually an upper bound, we can come as close to $\frac12$ as we want, and that's not as hard a bound to come up with ;)

Choosing $m = n$, the fraction simplifies to

$$\frac{2^{2n}}{2^{2n+1}+2^n} = \frac12 - \frac{2^{n-1}}{2^{2n+1}+ 2^n} > \frac12 - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.$$

Seeing that choosing $n\neq m$ doesn't give a value greater than $\frac12$ isn't too hard.

Comment: I think it's the most hated part of those lower and upper bounds/limits/whatever. Cause i was stuck with 
$\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}+1}$ and i had no idea what to do next with this. By not knowing what the answer should be, it's hard to come up with this $\dfrac12$ extraction. Anyway, thanks :-)

Comment: At this point, you identify and cancel the fastest growing term in the expression. Here it is obviously $2^n$ or $2^{n+1}$, canceling the first gives $\tfrac{1}{2+2^{-n}}$, and $2^{-n}$ converges to $0$.